# In Oracle, what grants do I need as a non-schema user to view rows in all_objects?

Tags: oracle-11g

I have two instances of an oracle 11g database, both have the same object definitions in the schema: tables with indexes and constraints, a sequence, and a stored procedure.

The facts of the case:

1. The first instance I login as the schema user "MYDBOWNER".
2. The second instance I login as a role-permissioned user "MYDBUSER", though the schema is still owned by "MYDBOWNER".
3. I run the following query to see the objects owned by user "MYDBOWNER":

> select * from all_objects where owner='MYDBOWNER';

1. As MYDBOWNER, I get a list of all the objects including the indexes (but not the constraints).
2. As MYDBUSER, I don't see the indexes, but I see the table, sequence and procedure.

The permissions for the role is correct (table has select, delete, update and insert, sequence has select, and procedure has execute). So why don't I see the indexes? Is there an additional grant that needs to be provided to the role for the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle data dictionary views that have the `ALL_` prefix provide information about objects that your user has access to.  Views that have the `DBA_` prefix provide information about all objects in the database.  And views that have the `USER_` prefix provide information about objects that you own.

In this case, `MYDBUSER` does not and can not have privileges on the indexes owned by `MYDBOWNER` because there are no privileges one can grant on individual indexes so it makes sense that `MYDBUSER` would not see the indexes in `ALL_OBJECTS`.  If `MYDBUSER` were granted access to `DBA_OBJECTS` or `DBA_INDEXES` (either individually or via the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege), you could query `DBA_OBJECTS` (or `DBA_INDEXES`) to get a list of all the indexes owned by `MYDBOWNER`.

Comment: This confirmed my own conclusions based on empirical evidence. It's a shame that our own DBA couldn't provide this information when I asked.